# How to define copy constructor and = operator override in class with pointers on class object?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy, variable-assignment

I heard that when there is a pointer in a class, there should always be copy constructor and = operator override in C++. I have searched about it and didn't found the explanation about when the pointer points to the class object.

To illustrate my problem:

```
class Figure
{
    Figure();
    Figure(const Figure& figure)
    Figure(float density);
    ~Figure();
    virtual float volume()=0;

    Figure *next;

protected:
    float density;
};

class Sphere: public Figure
{
    Sphere();
    Sphere(float r);
    Sphere(float r, float density);
    ~Sphere();
    float volume();

private:
    float r;
};
```

I tried making a copy constructor for class Figure. I get error on the last line saying "object of abstract class type Figure is not allowed". I don't know what am I doing wrong. And I don't know how to make assignment operator override.

```
Figure::Figure(const Figure& figure)
{
    this->tip = figure.tip;
    this->density = figure.density;
    if (figure.next)
        next = new Figure(*figure.next);
}
```

Comment: Actually, the rule is that whenever you have either a copy constructor, assignment operator, or destructor, you probably need all three. This is generally called "The Rule of Three" or "The Law of the Big Three."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical solution for this is to make the needed operation abstract, and support it in subclasses.

```
class Figure {

  virtual Figure * clone() const = 0;
};


class Sphere : public Figure {

  Figure * clone() const {
    return new Sphere(*this);
  }
};
```

Then of course implement the Sphere copy constructor properly.

Answer (score 1):

Put the copy constructor in Sphere instead.  You are trying to directly create a class of type Figure and this won't work as Figure is abstract.

Answer (score 0):

But according to your code `Figure` does not have a data member called `next`, only `Sphere` does.

Comment: In my original code it is in the Figure class. I will edit my post.